# Detecting corrupted jpg files before or during upload

Tags: file-upload, vbscript, asp-classic, jpeg

I have an ASP application that uses ASPImage.Image to resize the uploaded image and then save the file to the server and save it in the database.  However, it appears that if a user uploads a corrupted file the resulting image is blank white image.

I need a way to check if the file is corrupted before the image is passed to ASPImage.Image, that will then inform the user that the file is corrupted.

Can this be done with javascript, vbscript or ASPImage.Image itself?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Best Regards,

Paul Jacobs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to detect a corrupt image in either javascript or vbscript - you will need to try using [`ASPImage.Image`](http://www.serverobjects.com/comp/Aspimage.htm) directly.

It has an `Error` property, this will probably have an error detailing that a corrupt file has been loaded - did you try that? That is, if it is populated, chances are that the file was corrupt.

Additionally, the `LoadImage` method returns a boolean - I assume it will return false if the image couldn't be loaded due to corruption.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code here: http://forums.aspfree.com/code-bank-54/pure-asp-upload-script-with-additional-features-94647.html

Then check the image Width and Height - if 0 it means the uploaded file was not a valid image.

This is pure classic ASP code without third party components.